# Why does \fancyput affect the head of the first page?

Tags: fancyhdr

Here is my code

```latex
\documentclass[UTF8,a4paper,10.5pt,landscape]{ctexart}
\usepackage[bottom=3.2cm,top=2.6cm,left=3cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newsavebox{\zdx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\hspace{3ex}{{\heiti{\zihao{-3}{HuaiBei Shifan Daxue}}}\\
\vspace{1.5ex}
\hspace{12ex}\underline{\makebox[4em][c]{\textbf{{2015}}}}~\textbf{grade}~\underline{\makebox[6em][c]{\textbf{{~calculate}}}}~\textbf{expert}~\underline{\makebox[6em][c]{\textbf{{Shibian}}}}~\textbf{Course}~\underline{\makebox[8em][c]{\textbf{{2017～2018}}}}~\textbf{Year~~ }~ \underline{\makebox[2em][c]{\textbf{\kaishu{1}}}}\textbf{Term} \space \space {A} }
}
\fancyfoot[L]{{\noindent\hspace{3.5ex} \textbf{{Teacher}}\underline{\makebox[9em][c]{\textbf{{Test Paper}}}}\textbf{Sign}}\underline{\makebox[9em][c]{}}\textbf{
Sign}\underline{\makebox[9em][c]{}}}


\sbox{\zdx}
    {\parbox{22cm}{
    \centering\textbf{{\zihao{-4}{XueHao}}}\underline{\makebox[12em][c]{}} \textbf{\songti{\zihao{-4}{XingMing}}}\underline{\makebox[12em][c]{}}\textbf{\songti{\zihao{-4}{~BanJi}}}\underline{\makebox[12em][c]{}}\\
\vspace{4mm}
\textbf{{\zihao{-5}\makebox[11em][c]{\dotfill} Xian\makebox[12em][c]{\dotfill}Feng\makebox[12em][c]{\dotfill}Mi\makebox[11em][c]{\dotfill} }}
}}
%\setlength{\marginparsep}{-3.32cm}

\fancyput(-12mm,-8cm){\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{
\usebox{\zdx}}}

\fancyput*(1.00cm,-16.5cm){\tikz \draw[solid,line width=1pt](0,0) rectangle (25cm,16cm);}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

What I want is that every page has exactly the same head. But it shows that the head of the first page is different from others-the vertical position is a bit lower.

[image]

Why is that? And if I delete the `\fancyput` command, they become normal.